# txt出力を [x=1,ｙ＝10][x=2,y=20] みたいにきれいにしたい

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

xy対応したtxt書き込みを行いたい。
以下のコードだと、`[x=1,2,3~][y=10,20,30~]`になって見づらい。

```
from scipy.special import kv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(0.0,10,0.1)
f = lambda z: kv(5/3,z)
F = [quad(f,x,np.inf)[0]*x for x in xs]

with open("test4.txt","w") as f:
        print(xs,F,file=f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#zip)関数でまとめるのがオーソドックスな方法だと思いますがいかがでしょうか。

サンプルコード:

```
from scipy.special import kv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(0.0,10,0.1)
f = lambda z: kv(5/3,z)
F = [quad(f,x,np.inf)[0]*x for x in xs]

with open("test4.txt","w") as f:
    for x, y in zip(xs, F):
        print("[x=%.1f, y=%f]" % (x, y), file=f)
```

出力結果:

```
[x=0.0, y=-0.000000]
[x=0.1, y=0.818186]
[x=0.2, y=0.903386]
[x=0.3, y=0.917705]
[x=0.4, y=0.901937]
[x=0.5, y=0.870819]
(以下略)
```

Answer (score 0):

以下は [f-string(PEP 498: Literal String Interpolation)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) を使う場合です。

```py
with open('test4.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(''.join([f'[x={xs[i]:.1f}, y={F[i]:.6f}]\n' for i in range(len(xs))]))
```